# How can I read a .gz text file directly in C

Tags: gzip, fopen, fgets

I have a `log_date.txt` file that I wrote some C code around to parse and reduce it.  I parse it by using `fgets( buffer, 1024, fp )` to read each line into my *buffer* character array.  Everything is based around a text file with newlines, and I read text line by line.

In keeping these logs over time, each one has had `gzip -9` done on it resulting in `log_20200101.txt.gz`

Imagine having a file saved every day and when running my C code to read any chosen one you would have to manually do a `gunzip log_20200101.txt.gz` beforehand, and when done re-gzip it.  Is there a way in C to do an `fopen` and continue to use all my `fgets()` but have it happen on a `.gz` file?

Comment: You're serious?    The answer is a flat "no".   To read the file as text, you'll have to decompress it first.    There may be libraries available that will let you decompress the file to a temp file or stream first, but that seems kind of onerous.     I'm just curioius why you don't just create an enclosing script that will decompress the file, then invoke your log file processor against it, and remove the uncompressed file when you're done.    That would take three lines in just about any scripting or shell language that I'm aware of.

Comment: yes, and don't call me serious.

Answer (score 2):

boom

works inherently on both `log.txt` and `log.txt.gz`

```c
    # include <stdio.h>
    # include <stdlib.h>
    # include <zlib.h>

    # define LL 8192   /* line length maximum */

    int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
    {
       gzFile fp;
       char line[LL];

       fp = gzopen( "log.txt.gz", "r" );

       gzgets( fp, line, LL );

       while ( ! gzeof( fp ) )
       {
          printf("%s", line );
          gzgets( fp, line, LL );
       }

       gzclose( fp );
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `gcc yourprogram.c -lz`

Comment: Well, there's [this](https://www.lemoda.net/c/gzfile-read)...